# Change the Bounding Box in SceneKit

Tags: ios, scenekit

How can I change the size of the Bounding Box in SceneKit. I have a DAE file with one object and the bounding box is very large as shown below. This is in meters for ARKit app. How can I make it smaller.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't try to change to bounding box. You can in code but that does not change the size of the geometry. Use the `scale` property instead!

Comment: Does scale adjust the physics body geometry?

Comment: It should have the same effect as setting a position or rotation, so yes

Answer (score 2):

As followed **orangenkopf** answer's we can change its **scale** property in inspector itself,

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid scaling SCNNodes because it can complicate matters when applying different transforms. Scaling should be used when you actually need to have the model in multiple different sizes in the scene.

Instead, scale the model down to the desired size in a 3D software package that supports DAE (e.g. Blender).

Answer (score 1):

You can also see the actual bounding box size of your scaled model by placing it inside of another empty node. The parent node will show you the size after the child node has been scaled.

- [Parent with nested scaled child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QPbw.png)
- [Scaled Child](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3erB4.png)